# Sources for beautiful 3D models of humans

Tags: 3d, modeling

I can't seem to find beautiful models of humans in 3D. Here are some examples of what I am looking for. Where can I find models such as these?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! When a user provides an answer that solves your problem, you may upvote it and mark it as accepted using the checkmark. Your question seems a bit broad at first glance, and we normally ask users to be more specific so it may get closed. I'm not well versed enough in 3D to tell how many sources of good human 3D models there are out there and if it actually is too broad or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daz 3D. It is free. https://www.daz3d.com/

You can make some renders inside it or export the models to other aplications.

Another one is Makehuman http://www.makehumancommunity.org/content/downloads.html

Comment: wooooow it's like find another world! Thank you